# Atom, termination, virtual enviroment

Tags: python, virtualenv, atom-editor, termination

I have package **atom-python-virtualenv** and other package **termination** as terminal.

I am looking for solution which allow me to use automatically  virtual enviroment inside terminal.

It should work like this:

1. I choose virtual environment in atom-python-virtualenv paskage . ( I do not want to talk about how to create env.)
2. When i open terminal in termiantion package, I want to have the same virtual environment in terminal.

If no virtual environment selected, then terminal in normal mode.

Does Termination works automatically under virtualenv? I don't think so, because it do not show me.

Answer (score 0):

I create solution not exactly what i expect but is working.
Inside termination settings have we auto run command and there you have to write 3 commands.
1. Jump to env directory.
2. Start env
3. Come back to previous dir.

Look on print-screen:
[image]